# is this correct for DK V1.0.0?

Tags: win-universal-app

```
console.print('<Text>'>
```

prints text?

```
console.printVar(<Variable Name>)
```

prints variable?
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

It's it's correct, and there are more commands coming soon